# Click counter alternative

Tags: click, counter

I'm currently using GET to update my click counts into a database and then I redirect the user to the link by using

```
header('Location: '.$url);
```

Is there any better alternative way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm interested in understanding what's going on. Could you be more specific? You are taking the users request (eq for a download) like http://localhost/index.php?download=123 count the download and than hand over the real address via the header function call and the users client can than download/view the page?

Comment: merkuro, to be more specific, the links I mentioned are all external links, and the click gets update into the DB before a header function call is used to redirect the users to the external link.
I am wondering this is a good approach or is there any better approach(than using header('Location:'))?

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just serve the actual page after updating the count?  The only reason Google has to use redirection links is that they don't have control over the destination page.

Comment: Exactly my point. If I want to make sure EVERY visit is counted I probably don't want to hand out any other/real address so I maybe  lose track of some visitors. On the other hand why force the user to make two different requests if he only wants one site/download. For search engines this is probably not an ideal method, because they only store the "real url" circumventing your counting scheme. Another thing are screen readers. Don't know how they behave?!

Comment: merkuro, yes having a raw and a wrapper URL guarantees people are going to visit the raw URL directly, when you don't want that.  Just have one URL, and update the count as part of the page generation.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I've done it in the past, and it's worked fine for me.

I believe it's how Google does it too.